# Returning string from a function (c language)

Tags: c, string, return-type

I am trying to return a string from a function in few ways but without success.
Every time I get the same error.
Thank you for your help.
the code:

```
strcpy(temp, get_name());
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    scanf("%d", &i);
}
free(name_list);/*free the allocation of memory*/
return 0;
```

}

```
char *get_name()


{
int i=0;
char the_chosen_name[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
int rand_name = rand() % NUMBER_OF_STRING;
while (name_list[rand_name][i] != '\0')
    the_chosen_name[i] = name_list[rand_name][i];
the_chosen_name[i] = '\0';
//strcpy(the_chosen_name, name_list[rand_name]);
return the_chosen_name;
```

}

[option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyyHh.png)

[option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raHQ6.png)

edit:
in another way:
[option3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buZK7.png)
[WITHOUT A MORE VAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdeO2.png)

name_list is a global array of strings

thanks

Comment: there are a few problems with the **static** approach... but try `static char the_chosen_name[MAX_STRING_SIZE];`

Comment: the_choosen_name is on stack. You can't return a pointer to it. Either use static or take it's memory from malloc. get_name should be declared before it's usage as well ie above it's caller.

Comment: Your code snippets make no sense (they are incomplete)

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the function prototype as:

```
int get_name();
```

If so, change it to

```
char* get_name();
```

And you have another problem:
Your program returns a local array.

Use something like

```
void get_name(char *the_chosen_name){
    strcpy(the_chosen_name, name_list[rand() % NUMBER_OF_STRING]);
}
```

or allocate with `malloc` and `free` after you used it.

Comment: hi
thank you.
the function  must get nothing
i added an another code with  allocate

Comment: Have you declared the prototype? If you have, can you put the declaration here? If not, you should declare it as `char* get_name();`

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error you get is because the calling code is missing the function prototype.

So at start of your code, you need to add a declaration of the function like this:

```
char *get_name();
```

However, beside this compilation issue, there are severe other issues with your code: You cannot return buffer which is allocated on the stack.
When the call to get_name return, the memory for the buffer is reclaimed.

You can either use the heap, i.e. use malloc to allocate the buffer for `the_chosen_name` (and free it later), or give the function a buffer to use, a buffer which is allocated by the calling code.

e.g.
either have

```
the_chosen_name = malloc(sizeof(char)* MAX_STRING_SIZE)
```

or change the function signature to something like this:

```
void get_name( char *the_chosen_name)
```

and the calling code will allocate `the_chosen_name` variable either on stack or on heap.

Comment: I've edited the answer, you need to add declaration of the function at the start of your source file. but beside the compilation error, the code won't work, as you cannot return a buffer from stack